# Green light running in Monitor bottom

Tags: windows, windows-8, display, motherboard, desktop

I have LG 17'' LCD Monitor. From few days green light run in Monitor bottom under task bar.

[image]

In the screenshot, I draw the green line myself. But the real green line run exactly in that place every second or two second.

What is the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it there when the computer is off but the monitor is on? 
Is it there during boot? 
Is it there at the login screen? Is there a time it isn't their other than when the monitor is off?

Comment: It does not appear when the computer is OFF and the monitor is ON but while booting, login screen, after logging and all time it is showing green line running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not had this issue before to the extent where the line would not show up while the computer was off, but the computer is on. As a point in the possible correct direction, I would check the graphics card drivers to make sure that they are up to date, if they are, re install them. If you have custom graphics card software, check to make sure there aren't any weird settings checked. I don't know why it would help, but for some reason I think it would be a good idea to try hitting the auto-adjust button on the monitor to see if that fixes it.

Below are two more questions for you.

1. When did this problem start, or has it always been there?
2. Did something change right before the problem started (Windows Updates, new graphics card, etc)?

Comment: @CodeProtocol: which part of my answer fixed your problem? If we know, this could help others that have the same exact issue in the future.